# What are several ideal icons for a web homepage?

Tags: website-design

I am creating a portfolio website for a college class and my homepage content contains a Welcome, About and Contact paragraph. What are several icons I could use that appropriately represent the Welcome and About sections?

Comment: Right now I am still planning my design and looking at icons. Not coding anything yet.

Comment: It's always helpful if you do a bit of legwork yourself to at least provide some direction as to overall design which may fit with the concept. Otherwise, answers simply become a random shopping list of icons which is rarely helpful to anyone.

Comment: Any search for "welcome/about/contact icon" will give you big piles of suggestions. For us to be even remotely helpful, you need to show and tell what you think would work/not work; examples and some concrete questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by making some research first. You can start with [Icon Finder](https://www.iconfinder.com/) first to see what icons you get there based on your keywords and select a few for reference. You can use them directly but first read the licence and make sure you have the rights to do so. If you don't find what you need there, go to [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com/) and do another search. Based on a simple research like this you can see what symbols/icons fit your needs and then dive directly into testing with them / designing your own set.

Answer (score 1):

There are as many ideas as many designers. I agree with Ilan. Standards keep you away from incomprehension. Don't think too much and use ready-made.

Answer (score 0):

If you look for finished icons I can suggest [Shuttestock](http://www.shutterstock.com/) site...

in the searching window you can insert "welcome icon" "information icon" and choose one of thousands examples....

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome: welcome matt, handshake, smiling face, open door, open sign;
About: 'i' for info, book, bulleted list, question mark, face, diary, résumé;
Contact: letter, pen, speech bubble, phone, mouse, mouth, stamp, mailbox

This is just basic brainstorming and word association. Think fast and just write down any word that comes to mind for each subject--even if it's absurd or only remotely related. Spend no more than a minute on each word. That should give you a good few dozen ideas that hopefully will lead to a solution for you.

Before you go too far, however, perhaps rethink the need for icons. While they say pictures are worth a thousand words, that's not always true--especially when we're talking iconography. Often a single word *is* worth more.

Comment: I second the notion that sometimes a single word can be more than enough.